# A function does not wait for another function to execute

Tags: angularjs

This is my service

```
var validateEmailService=function (validateEmailUrl,validateEmailParameters,email) {
    var url=validateEmailUrl +'?';
    angular.forEach(validateEmailParameters,function (value,key) {
        url=url +key +'='+ value.parameter +'&';
    });
    url=url+'email='+email;
    $http.get(url).then(function (value) {
        var result = value;
        var smtpCheck = result.data.smtp_check;
        var mxRecordsCheck = result.data.mx_found;
       // console.log(smtpCheck ,mxRecordsCheck);
        if (smtpCheck === true && mxRecordsCheck === true){
            //console.log('In');
            return true;
        }
        //console.log('Out');
    });
};

var sendEmailService=function (sendEmailApiUrl,emailData,config,email,firstName,lastName) {
    emailData = JSON.stringify(emailData);
    emailData = emailData.replace("%%Email%%", email);
    emailData = emailData.replace("%%FirstName%%", firstName);
    emailData = emailData.replace("%%LastName%%", lastName);
    emailData = JSON.parse(emailData);
    $http.post(sendEmailApiUrl, emailData, config);
};

return {
    validateEmailService: validateEmailService,
    sendEmailService: sendEmailService
};
```

And I have called these functions here in the controller

```
var validate = emailService.validateEmailService(validateEmailUrl, validateEmailParameters,$scope.patient.Email);
if (validate === true) {
    emailService.sendEmailService(sendEmailApiUrl, emailData, config,$scope.patient.Email,$scope.patient.givenName,$scope.patient.familyName);
    messagingService.showMessage("info", "REGISTRATION_LABEL_SAVED");
    $state.go("patient.edit", {
        patientUuid: $scope.patient.uuid
    });
}
else {
    alert('Email does not exist');
}
```

So when the if statement is executed validate does not contain anything and it automatically goes to the else part even when validate should be true.

Comment: You are working with Promises. Add a `return` before `$http.get` to return an [(angular) HTTP Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns). Then once you properly return it, your `validate` will become a Promise that you need to resolve with `validate.then(function(res){ if(res === true){...} else{...} })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the promise instead, the `$http.get` is asynchronous

```
var validateEmailService=function (validateEmailUrl,validateEmailParameters,email) {
    var url=validateEmailUrl +'?';
    angular.forEach(validateEmailParameters,function (value,key) {
        url=url +key +'='+ value.parameter +'&';
    });
    url=url+'email='+email;

    // IMPORTANT PART: USE RETURN
    return $http.get(url).then(function (value) {
        var result = value;
        var smtpCheck = result.data.smtp_check;
        var mxRecordsCheck = result.data.mx_found;
       // console.log(smtpCheck ,mxRecordsCheck);
        if (smtpCheck === true && mxRecordsCheck === true){
            //console.log('In');
            return true;
        }
        //console.log('Out');
    });
};
```

And then in your controller:

```
emailService.validateEmailService(validateEmailUrl, validateEmailParameters,$scope.patient.Email).then(function(validate){
    if (validate === true) {
        emailService.sendEmailService(sendEmailApiUrl, emailData, config,$scope.patient.Email,$scope.patient.givenName,$scope.patient.familyName);
        messagingService.showMessage("info", "REGISTRATION_LABEL_SAVED");
        $state.go("patient.edit", {
            patientUuid: $scope.patient.uuid
        });
    } else {
        alert('Email does not exist');
    }
})
```

Also, see this [link](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) about promises